# A sector of a circle has the area of 12 cm squared. If the angle at the centre is 60 degrees, calculate the diameter of the circle.

Tags: circles

The answer I got was $45.8$cm but it seems wrong. I did

$$
A=\pi r^2
$$

$$
12= \frac{60}{360} \pi r^2
$$

$$
\frac{12}{\pi} \cdot \frac{360}{60}=r=22.9183118
$$

$$
d=45.8
$$

Comment: You could check your answer. $A=\frac 14 \pi d^2$.  If we plug in your answer, the area of the circle comes out about $1647.5$, far too large.

Comment: It seems you forgot to take the square root of $r^2$...

Comment: Now that it is formatted, one can see that (besides changing $r$ to $x$ at one point) you lost the square on $r$, so did not take the square root.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I've accurately transcribed your approach, your error is that you didn't take the square root.  You should have $r = \sqrt{\frac{72}{\pi}} \doteq 4.7873$, and then $d \doteq 9.5746$.

Answer (score 1):

Between the second and third line you lost the square on $r$, so did not take a square root that you should have.